# How to get the desired array from an array list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm creating a calculator just to learn more about jQuery and JavaScript. I've created buttons for each number from 0 to 9. As the buttons are clicked the textbox should have the clicked value in. I wanted to create an array which contains all the values from 0 to 9 and the mathmetical signs, that's where I've failed. What I'm trying to do is instead of copying and pasting the code below to be able to get my buttons work, I want an array that can dynamically achieve it at once.

This is the necessary part of my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
        jQuery(".numbers").on('click', function () {
            jQuery("#textbox").val(jQuery("#textbox").val() + numbers.valueOf());
        });
    });
```

See I've tried to use `.valueOf()` method but it gets all the components. Could you show me how it's done? I've also created a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weo9z2r5/10/) so perhaps you'd like to take a closer look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? When clicking on `#one` that it adds `1` to your textbox? Why are you not just using `jQuery("#textbox").val() + '1'`?

Comment: I wanted to create a dynamic system for it. I've tried that before but I want to get rid of copy-paste that method for all the inputs that are required in a calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beaten to the punch by others, but make it as generic as possible so youre not repeating code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("input").on('click', function () {
        jQuery("#textbox").val(jQuery("#textbox").val()+this.value);
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/weo9z2r5/7/)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try

```
jQuery("#textbox").val() + numbers[0])
```

Click [here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/weo9z2r5/5/)!

updated [link](http://jsfiddle.net/weo9z2r5/8/)!

or just use
give a class name to every button say "button"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".button").on('click', function () {
        jQuery("#textbox").val(jQuery("#textbox").val() + this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: The demo does not work. It works for only 1, not the all numbers.

Comment: I have updated the code. It will solve your problem.

Comment: You can change the selectors accordingly. you are  welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a class to your buttons and use it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".button").on('click', function () {
        jQuery("#textbox").val(jQuery("#textbox").val() + this.value);
    });
});

<input type="button" class="button" style="width:45px; height:45px;" value="1" id="one" />
<input type="button" class="button" style="width:45px; height:45px;" value="2" id="two" />
<input type="button" class="button" style="width:45px; height:45px;" value="3" id="three" />
```

Comment: Yes, silly me, I forgot the fact about adding a `class`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button the button has value we will pick that using `parseInt($(e.target).val())` add to what was there

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          var sign = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
          jQuery("#one").on('click', function (e) {
              Query("#textbox").val(jQuery("#textbox").val() + parseInt($(e.target).val()));
          });
    });
```

Use the event button to get value

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add class to all numeric inputs. For example

```
<input type="button" class="number" style="width:45px; height:45px;" value="3" id="three" />
```

After this you easily can do what you need

```
$(".number").on('click', function (event) {
        $("#textbox").val($("#textbox").val() + $(event.target).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

```
(function($){

    var sign = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"];
    var text = $('#textbox');

    $("input[type='button']").not('#equal').on('click', function () {
        var self = $(this);
        text.val(text.val() + self.val());
    });

    $("#equal").on('click', function(){
        text.val(eval(text.val()));
    });

})(jQuery);
```

So by using **eval()** method, you will be able to evaluates the JavaScript code represented as a string.

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/geswjmyp/)